# Magento 2.1.6 Cannot show more than 1000 products in frontend category pages

Tags: product, category, frontend, magento2.1.6

I have a category with more than `10k products` But in front-end `shows only 999 products` in category page.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps :

1. Run index command
2. Clear cache, generation, page_cache under `var` folder.

Comment: i did reindex and removed cache, generation , page_cache. But nothing happend

Comment: can u please check products visibility status like [Not Visible Individually, Catalog, Search], In-stock/out-of-stock. And also see the configuration of product/category and also in products showing code also if any custom value has set or not that to visible only limited products.

Comment: All products are  visible , instock  and also not set any limitatiin to  product to visble . But not working ...........

Comment: hi sorry for late reply and can u please update Magento version 2.1.6 to 2.1.7 may be a chance to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response actually im fix that issue in Magento 2.1.6

Comment: how u fixed ?? may I know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the `const RANGE_CATEGORY_STEP = 5000;` to `const RANGE_CATEGORY_STEP = 100000;` from `AbstractAction` file.
2. Change the   `<from>0</from><size>50000</size>` to `<from>0</from><size>100000</size>` do this in all three in `search_request` file.